# How to unwrap a result object of an async method neatly?

Tags: c#, async-await

I have an async method which gives me the `IEnumerable<T>` after querying a cosmos db container.

```
var count = (await myContainer.QueryAsync<int>(myQuery)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Is there a (neater) way to get first item from that async method without that whole *wrapping in brackets* thing? Something like the below?

```
var count = myContainer.QueryAsync<int>(myQuery).Await().FirstOrDefault();
```

And I strictly [don't want to use the `GetAwaiter()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.getawaiter?view=netframework-4.8#remarks)

Comment: `QueryAsync<int>` has a return type `Task<IEnumerable<int>>`? Then there is nothing much you can do unfortunately. `IAsyncEnumerable` would have been your friend.

Comment: The only method call that can replace the [`await`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await) operator is the [`ContinueWith`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith), which would make the resulting code even uglier.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = await myContainer.QueryAsync<int>(myQuery);
var count = result.FirstOrDefault();
```

Much neater.

There is no non-blocking way to omit the `await` (except for the `GetAwaiter()` which is ugly anyway), you can't wrap it in an extension method, as it would also have to return a `Task<IEnumerable<int>>`. The best you can do is make your code readable by splitting it into two statements.

Answer (score 1):

With the following extension method:

```cs
public async static Task<T> FirstOrDefaultAsync<T>(this Task<IEnumerable<T>> taskCollection) {
    return (await taskCollection).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

you could reduce your call to a neater

```cs
var count = await myContainer.QueryAsync<int>(myQuery).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

but that's not making the "whole wrapping in brackets thing" disappear.